# Combine vectors and tables in R

Tags: r, merge, data.table, dplyr

I encountered a problem during a simple merging task and I'm looking for a better solution. I'm creating tables from a series of surveys (which I cannot merge). The tables have the same values, but different dimensions.

The data is below.

table x

```
x <- structure(c(44L, 167L), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("similar", "compete")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
```

table y

```
y <- structure(c(69L, 213L, 154L, 4L, 29L, 32L), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("other", "compete", "similar"), c("college", "no college"
    )), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

table z

```
z <- structure(c(13L, 38L, 43L, 46L, 131L, 172L, 37L, 177L, 122L, 
8L, 34L, 12L, 16L, 114L, 70L, 20L, 17L, 27L), .Dim = c(3L, 6L
), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("other", "compete", "similar"
), c("skipped", "Democrat", "Independent", "Libertarian", "Republican", 
"other")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")
```

My solution was to use `cbind` and take out the disimilar columns like so

```
cbind(y[-1,], x,  z[-1,-1])
```

Then I learned that in R, row names are unreliable and the table turns out different if the order of cbind is mixed up. This makes creating table very unreliable. I'd like to be able to merge 3 or more tables, without having to worry that the order of the merge is messing up the data.

What is a better way of combining tables with different dimensions?

I suspect that there might be a great way to `data.table` or `dplyr` but haven't figured it out.

Thanks and please let me know if i can make this question any more clear.

Comment: You may be able to use `cbind(y[rownames(x), ], x, z[rownames(x), -1])` without worry.  You'll get the proper order that way

Comment: A `table` is pretty much a terminal object, not very amenable to further manipulation beyond `addmargins` and `prop.table`. That's the one place where rownames are okay, I think. If you want to do something fancy, do it before using `table()`, I'd say.

Comment: Also, general note: it's preferred that you not tag data.table simply because you want a solution that uses it. As far as I know, the dplyr authors don't care, though.

Comment: @Frank I'm trying to compare crosstab results from different survey populations asked the same question (than plot them). Do you recommend using a different object to look at the tabulations? Maybe a data.frame?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of anything for plotting tables of higher than two dimensions.

Comment: @Frank none of the tables will be higher than 2-dimensions. It's just adding rows or columns based on different populations. It's nothing fancier than a cluster bar chart. Just looking for a way to create the data tables from separate sources

Comment: Your table *should* be three dimensions, since you're talking about comparing cross tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm missing the point here and also not sure how "automated" you need the process to be, but this might be helpful:

```
x <- structure(c(44L, 167L), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
  c("similar", "compete")), .Names = ""), class = "table")

y <- structure(c(69L, 213L, 154L, 4L, 29L, 32L), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
  c("other", "compete", "similar"), c("college", "no college"
  )), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")

z <- structure(c(13L, 38L, 43L, 46L, 131L, 172L, 37L, 177L, 122L, 
                 8L, 34L, 12L, 16L, 114L, 70L, 20L, 17L, 27L), .Dim = c(3L, 6L
                 ), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("other", "compete", "similar"
                 ), c("skipped", "Democrat", "Independent", "Libertarian", "Republican", 
                      "other")), .Names = c("", "")), class = "table")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# create data frames from tables
x = data.frame(x)
names(x) = c("group","x")

y = data.frame(y) %>% spread(Var2,Freq)
names(y)[1] = "group"

z = data.frame(z) %>% spread(Var2, Freq)
names(z)[1] = "group"

# join data frames
x %>% inner_join(y, by="group") %>% inner_join(z, by="group")

#     group   x college no college skipped Democrat Independent Libertarian Republican other
# 1 similar  44     154         32      43      172         122          12         70    27
# 2 compete 167     213         29      38      131         177          34        114    17
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below binds your data by row and fills the values of missing columns with NA. From there on you should be able to carry on with your analysis.

```
library(plyr)

my_list <- list(as.data.frame(x),
                as.data.frame(y),
                as.data.frame(z))


Reduce(x = my_list, f = rbind.fill)

# resulting data.frame

      Var1 Freq        Var2
1  similar   44        <NA>
2  compete  167        <NA>
3    other   69     college
4  compete  213     college
5  similar  154     college
6    other    4  no college
7  compete   29  no college
8  similar   32  no college
9    other   13     skipped
10 compete   38     skipped
11 similar   43     skipped
12   other   46    Democrat
13 compete  131    Democrat
14 similar  172    Democrat
15   other   37 Independent
16 compete  177 Independent
17 similar  122 Independent
18   other    8 Libertarian
19 compete   34 Libertarian
20 similar   12 Libertarian
21   other   16  Republican
22 compete  114  Republican
23 similar   70  Republican
24   other   20       other
25 compete   17       other
26 similar   27       other
```